# Custom MFA TOTP - How do you deploy the backend REST API to Azure App Service

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

When I click on the button to Deploy nothing happens and it say resource not found.  I am trying to deploy the Azure App Service for generating the QR code for MFA TOTP.

Comment: I presume you have an Azure subscription and are using VS? Have you logged into the subscription from the Cloud services tab? Do you see your subscription as per this flow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your backend REST API to Azure App Service from the IDE.

If you are using VS Code, please follow below procedure :

1. Add Azure App Service extension and sign in with your azure account.
2. Click on deploy to web app and select your subscription.
3. If the web app is already created, please select your  existing web app.
4. If the web app is not created, please click on create   web app ( advanced) and give the web app name.
5. Select your resource group and select runtime stack. Select OS. Select the location
6. Select your App Service Plan. You can enable application insights or skip for now.

Your  API will be  deployed to Azure App Service.

Similar way, you can deploy your  REST API to Azure App service using other IDEs like Visual Studio.